# Errors occur when importing products with images in magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-images, importexport

At the 1st time "image not valid error" occurred after copying all images to `site-name/media/import/`. that error is not occurred now.But the new errors are occurred.

I have tried all kind of steps to import products.I have around 2000 products in my old site.Now I want to move those products to new site.But I cant import 2000 products.I have tried it with `System ->import/export -> Data flow profiles -> Import all Products`.But all the time different kind of errors occurred.So now I am trying with only 2 products.But still cant see any success.Help me if you have proper steps with image import too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Copy all folders from source magento root/media/catalog/product/
>
> 2.Paste all folders in target magento root/media/import/
>
> 3.Open Source Magento Admin Panel. System-->Export/Import-->Dataflow Profiles-->Export all Products-->Run Profile TAB--> Run Profile in
>    Popup. PLease Wait till all products are exported. After that open
>    source magento root/var/export/ There will be your csv file with all
>    product details.
>
> 4.Open Target Magento Admin Panel.  System-->Export/Import-->Dataflow Profiles-->Import all Products-->Upload File Tab-->
>
> 5.Select your csv file from step 3--> click sav and continue-->run profile tab-->select your file-->Run Profile in Popup
>
> 6.Refresh your cache and do indexing if required.

Answer (score 0):

you should make an export first of maybe only 1 product. Then you see, which fields you need.

In the type column for example, there hast to be sth like simple, bundle, configurable ...

Comment: Yes, there is value "simple" in type column